# Displaying feed with the correct html character entities

Tags: php, string, html-entities

I have feed that's already broken down into the content I need.  Part of that content contains things such as `&\;` and `"\;`.

I'm using PHP's `str_replace()` to find and replace them to be their correct html character entities (ex. `&amp;`). However, it won't find this:

```
 $find = array('&\;', '"\;', '\;');
```

And I would replace them like this:

```
 $replace = array('&amp;', '&quot;', '&#59;');
```

What am I missing in order for the function to find them?

---

```
<ul>
    <li>Story Time with Captain Fishbones</li>
    <li>Flashback</li>
    <li>The Office</li>
    <li>The Life &amp\; Music of Ella Fitzgerald</li>
    <li>Circus in the Park</li>
    <li>Symphonicity</li>
    <li>Wreck of the Dictator</li>
    <li>Fireworks</li>  
</ul>
<h3>Thursday, Aug 12</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Historic Villages Tour</li>
    <li>The Janitors</li>
    <li>Mitchell&#039\;s Mayhem</li>
    <li>&quot\;1607 First Landing&quot\; by Chip Fortier</li>
    <li>Adam Queen followed by Randy Hermoso</li>

    <li>The Life &amp\; Music of Ella Fitzgerald</li>
    <li>Shipwrecks and Ghost Lore</li>
    <li>Black White Blues</li>
    <li>Wreck of the Dictator</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what does your data look like? could you provide a snippet of your data and explain what you what do achieve?

Comment: Could you also add your current php-code? There might be an error in your function calls.

Comment: Did my answer help you or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use [html_special_chars()](http://php.net/html_special_chars) to print the content.
Also I think that your $find variable has wrong escape sequences.